# What is the bug in this javascript code using Raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, raphael

```
<html>
 <body>
<script src="raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>// Each of the following examples create a canvas that is 320px wide by 200px high
// Canvas is created at the viewport’s 10,50 coordinate
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
// Canvas is created at the top left corner of the #notepad element
// (or its top right corner in dir="rtl" elements)
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("notepad"), 320, 200);
// Same as above
var paper = Raphael("notepad", 320, 200);
// Image dump

var c = paper.circle(50, 50, 40);
var set = Raphael(["notepad", 320, 200, {
    type: "rect",
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
    stroke: "#f00"
}, {
    type: "text",
    x: 30,
    y: 40,
    text: "Dump"
}]);
</script>
 </body>
```

I am just testing/learning Raphael and am running this HTML code in XAMPP , in ubuntu , using Chrome Browser . But nothing is getting displayed . Though , I have the raphael.js file in the same folder of the html file .

What is the bug ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use Raphael so I don't know the inner workings, but on the first look it seems to me that you are missing an html element whoose id is `notepad`. Like some container which will hold the canvas

```
<div id="notepad">
</div>
```

Comment: +1 It works (but it need to be inserted **before** the javascript code).